# How to get an XML report out of MSBuild Code Analysis

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, code-analysis

Running MSBuild with `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true`on a C# project does generate the code analysis warnings on the build output, but what's the switch that lets me export these warnings (only the code analysis warnings not the entire build output) to an XML file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The XML report is generated by default. The file name is `MyAssembly.dll.CodeAnalysisLog.xml` or `MyApplication.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml`, you should be able to find it in the output folder for you project.

To change name of the XML report, use parameter `CodeAnalysisLogFile`:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=MyXmlReport.xml
```

Comment: This works! Is it possible to run this at solution(.sln) level? Also, can we change the .xml report file to be generated in a different directory level instead of the default "bin/Release" directory location? 
Example: /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\xyz\abc\MyXmlReport.xml
I am trying to integrate this in Azure Pipeline.