# Msbuild not producing XML file with code analysis

Tags: c#, msbuild, code-analysis

I have been digging but cannot find the answer - I THOUGHT I had found it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472569/how-to-get-an-xml-report-out-of-msbuild-code-analysis) but it is not working on my system.  The only difference that I can see is that I am giving msbuild a solution file and not an individual project file - must I do it at the project level to get output?  The command line I entered was:

```
msbuild Interlink.NET.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=test.xml
```

Obviously, test.xml was not created or I would not be asking this question...

The solution is a C# project in VS2015, in case any of that effects things.  In Visual Studio, I can select "Analyze | Run Code Analysis on Solution" and things work as expected.  I want to incorporate the analysis into an automated build process and produce an XML file with the analysis.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm running into the same problem with running `msbuild` on a solution (`.sln`) file. The code analysis output is written to the console, but no xml log file is written.

Comment: The problem for me was two-fold. On the one hand, a few rule sets were missing (not installed) and secondly the code analysis would only run for certain combinations of platform/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes the command that you used is correct and will work for .sln files.
Only a `test.xml` file will be created inside each of the constituent projects.
And these copies will contain the static code analysis reports of that specific prject.
It will not be created at the level of the .sln file.

Comment: can we change the .xml report file to be generated in a different directory level instead of the default "bin/Release" directory location? I am trying to integrate this in Azure Pipeline.
Example: /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\xyz\abc\MyXmlReport.xml

Answer (score 0):

I ran `msbuild` with the following arguments and the xml file got produced in the output directory, **but** the filename I've given got ignored. It was named `vc.nativecodeanalysis.all.xml` instead.

```
msbuild Project.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=test.xml /t:Clean;Rebuild
```

`Project.sln` is a C++ project in VS2017 though.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below forum

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472569/how-to-get-an-xml-report-out-of-msbuild-code-analysis](http://msbuild%20MyProject.csproj%20/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true%20/p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=MyXmlReport.xml)

`msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=MyXmlReport.xml`